# vi regex no match

Tags: regular-expression

I have this

```
os.environ.get("DB_NAME")
```

and I am trying to use the vi regex command

```
% s/os\.environ\.get\("DB_NAME"\)/db_name/gc
```

to match that. I used it to **change** flaskdb to `os.environ.get("DB_NAME")`, but this won't match to change it to `db_name`.

On further investigation I was able to match it by removing the **parenthesis**.

How come I was able to escape the parenthesis to match the first change but not the second set of changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vi uses Ex patterns, which are a superset of POSIX Basic (obsolete, according to `man re_format`) REs. This means that `\(` and `\)` are used for *grouping*, not to represent literal parentheses (as in "modern", or Extended, REs).

You can also find this information in Vim at `:help pattern`, which explains that with the default magic settings `(` is literal and `\(` opens a group. With `\v` very-magic, this is reversed to make grouping easier (among other changes).

So, I would write

```
:%substitute/os\.environ\.get("DB_NAME")/db_name/gc
```

to change the entire `os.environ.get("DB_NAME")` expression, or

```
:%substitute/DB_NAME/db_name/gc
```

to only affect the `DB_NAME`.

With Vim, I might use a pattern like `os\.environ\.get("\zsDB_NAME\ze")` to match `DB_NAME` within `os.environ.get("")`, and I might use a replacement like `\L&` to lowercase the match (change `DB_NAME` to `db_name`).

An alternate idea is to `/DB_NAME`, or press `*` if you are already on the word, then `gugn` to lowercase the match. Then `.` jumps to the next match and lowercases, while `n` only jumps to the next match (so you can skip and act by combining `n` and `.`).

Comment: Excellent very informative